# For and If/else in python to check and add information to json

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hello I'm having trouble making a loop of if else in python, I need my if to check that there is a description "quantity" in my product and if there is to leave it as it is else to add in "quantity" : 0,

I want to make my for check that the "quantity" is present and if it's not to add it in.
But I have no idea how to make this for if else combo

```
data = json.load(json_data)
for product in data:
    if product ["quantity"] in data

    else 'w' product ["quantity":0]
```

It's going to show the result hopefully with this

```
with open('br2.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_data:
    json_data.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False))
    json_data.close()
```

I want it to go over a json like this

```
  [{"id": 2162952, "name": "Kit Gamer acer - Notebook + Headset + Mouse", 
  "price": 25599.0, "category": "Eletrônicos"}, 
  {"id": 3500957, "name": "Monitor 29 LG FHD Ultrawide com 1000:1 de 
  contraste", "quantity": 18, "price": 1559.4, "category": 
 "Eletrônicos"},
  {"id": 1911864, "name": "Mouse Gamer Predator cestus 510 Fox Preto", 
  "price": 699.0, "category": "Acessórios"}]
```

And return it like this

```
  [{"id": 2162952, "name": "Kit Gamer acer - Notebook + Headset + 
   Mouse","quantity": 0, "price": 25599.0, "category": "Eletrônicos"}, 
  {"id": 3500957, "name": "Monitor 29 LG FHD Ultrawide com 1000:1 de 
  contraste", "quantity": 18, "price": 1559.4, "category": "Eletrônicos"},
  {"id": 1911864, "name": "Mouse Gamer Predator cestus 510 Fox Preto", 
  "price": 699.0, "category": "Acessórios"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if product is a dictionary you can check if the key "quantity" is not in product and in that case add that key with value 0 with:

```
if "quantity" not in product:
        product["quantity"] = 0
```

Comment: great, can you vote this as a correct answer, thanks